# Can you style Google Forms (from Google Apps)?

Tags: google-forms

While Google makes themes available to style forms in Google Docs, there seems to be no provision for styling forms yourself.

I have a two-column layout and want the form on the right. There are various problems, such as the textarea overflowing the column. Since it's in an Iframe there's not way to wedge in a stylesheet or a jQuery/javascript fix.

The only suggestion I've found is grabbing the source of the iframe and dropping it into my own HTML, but this breaks the built-in validation and is too hack-ish.

Answer (score 2):

Besides from the standard layout that Google gives you there is not much you can do. Anyway, you can try building your form with Google Apps Script
http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/service_ui.html
it's JavaScript Server Side and it uses the same tools as GWT. In a couple of hours you can style your form (there is only one problem: right now only Google users can access the form).

Comment: The level of effort doesn't justify going this route. A good idea though.