# How can I change Google Forms style to put multiple textboxes on the same line?

Tags: google-forms, css

I want to conduct a recognition task for Chinese characters online. People who fill out the task will have to read the Chinese character, and type out the pronunciation of the character in English *pinyin*, and the meaning in English. The end goal of what I want to create will look something like this:

[image]

Now, by far the easiest to use program out there is Google Forms. I'm aware that there are programs like Ibex, Linger and WebExp, but all of them have a fairly steep learning curve, and as far as I'm aware, need some special magic to distribute the form to users online. If I can get this working on Forms, all I need to do is send people the link, and they're good to go.

The problem is, I can't make Google Forms look compact and neat like this mock-up. This is the best I could come up with:

[image]

Is there any way to alter the stylesheet on Google Forms, so that the textboxes are more compact and can all fit on a single line, as in the example? And furthermore, is there a way to ensure that this stylesheet will work for all users who open the Form?

Alternatively, is there a relatively unchallenging program that I can use to design web experiments like this, in a format like this, and be able to distribute it easily without requiring participants to download Java or jump through other hoops?

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92082/88163, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14392/88163