# How to change font style for Description, Response and other fields?

Tags: google-forms

My research shows that **old version of Google forms allowed to set different font styles for EACH type of field** (question Title, Description, Response etc.).

**It used to be possible to switch to the old version** of Google Forms and do it, but it is **currently disabled** - all new forms are created under new UI.

---

You can see the exact problem in this video:
https://youtu.be/SCs8jxZtrTU?t=90

The woman changes font to Decorative, but the only thing changed are question titles.

My question: how to achieve that font change in all fields, not just the title? By any means, can be complicated workaround.

Comment: Welcome. This look as question were you are asking us to recommend/find a tool for you but that is out of the scope of this site. I suggest you to ask on [meta.se] if there is as site for a question like this. (it could be [softwarerecs.se] but first check their how to ask guidelines)

Comment: Related: 1) [Apply custom CSS styles to Google Forms](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92082/88163) 2) [Can you style Google Forms (from Google Apps)?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14392/88163)

Comment: Thank you for answer and looking into my case. Actually I am not asking for a recommendation for a tool - I was expecting to find an option/workaround for this **within Google Forms** and if you confirm it is completely undoable as it seems to be, then I am asking for a workaround that involves anything (but at the end of the day I wish to have the formatting change in Google Forms, not another forms software - there's plenty of it, I know). I am just psycho-dedicated to have the font change apply to all fields in Google Forms. :D Hope this comment made clarified my exact intentions.:)